# How do I extract column names in list of data frames?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

My problem is this: I have a list of data.frames and create a distance matrix for each data.frame. Then, I want to extract the minimum distance for each row and the corresponding column name. I know how to do the first but not the latter. I (hope) this is an easy fix but I can't wrap my head around it. Here is my attempt:

```
#create list of matrices
A = matrix(c(5, 4, 2, 1, 5, 7), nrow=3, ncol=3, byrow = TRUE)        
B = matrix(c(2, 5, 10, 9, 8, 7), nrow=3, ncol=3, byrow = TRUE)
list.matrix <- list(A,B)

#create names
column.names <- c("A", "B", "C")
df = data.frame(column.names)

#name rows
list.matrix<-lapply(list.matrix, function(x){colnames(x)<- as.character(df$column.names); x})

#Then I can get the smallest value by row
min.list.value <- lapply(list.matrix, function(x) apply(x, 1, min)) #smallest value per row
min.list.row <-  lapply(list.matrix, function(x) (max.col(-x))) #column index of smallest value

#But how do I get the colname of the row with the smallest value??
#Something like this, which does not work (obviously)
min.list.colname <- lapply(list.matrix, function(x) apply(x, 1, colnames(min))) #smallest value per row
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
min.list.colname <- lapply(min.list.row, function(x) column.names[x])
```

You can use this to get values, column indices, and column names

```
library(purrr)
library(magrittr)


list.matrix %>% 
  lapply(apply, 1, which.min) %>% 
  imap(~data.frame(value = list.matrix[[.y]][cbind(seq_along(.x), .x)]
                  , ColName = colnames(list.matrix[[.y]])[.x]
                  , ColIndex = .x))

# [[1]]
#   value ColName ColIndex
# 1     2       C        3
# 2     1       A        1
# 3     2       C        3
# 
# [[2]]
#   value ColName ColIndex
# 1     2       A        1
# 2     7       C        3
# 3     2       A        1
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great! But this only works in case my column.names are in a data.frame. What if they are in a list of data.frames? e.g. `#create names in list:

column.names.list <- list(df$column.names, df$column.names)

for (i in 1:length(list.matrix)){
  colnames(list.matrix[[i]]) <- column.names.list[[i]]
}
lapply(list.matrix, colnames)`

Comment: @P.Bear I've edited the code so it grabs the `colnames` of the current matrix, instead of using an external `column.names` variable.

Comment: Thanks! Brilliant. This works like a charm on my real data!

Answer (score 2):

Or:

```
(min.list.colname <- lapply(list.matrix, function(x) colnames(x)[apply(x, 1, which.min)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Column names can be obtained as `colnames(data_frame)`.

Now use transpose to get the column names as a list:

```
colnames_df <- t(t(colnames(data_frame))
```